# How should I go About extending my range?

Tags: vocal-range

I am 18 and have been singing for years now, I got very dedicated when I was 15 and for two years I have been improving my self and I have already broken into a range that I thought I could not sing (it is actually not that high). I have a range of about E♭2 to F#4 if I stretch it a little (Although I am almost certain that it is unhealthy for me to sing that high the current way because I could be singing it wrong). I consider myself a baritone and I just want to hit up to a G#4 in mixed or chest. I already can sing falsetto but singing a G in falsetto is not as fun or as flashy. I just wanted to know what advice anyone has for me to help me get to that range, or just sing more healthy and improve my current range if I can't sing higher.

If it helps, my inspiration is from Michael Bublé, and Frank Sinatra. They are the reason I want to sing into the upper range of the Baritone voice. Also,some advice to help me sing D4-F4 stronger and healthier would be appreciated.

If I need a vocal trainer (not that I even know how to get one, or one that is qualified) how long on average would it take. Now I am patient and I will work until I get it and I don't have a deadline or anything but I just wan't to know.

Comment: A voice teacher won't just help you sing better, they will also help you avoid damaging your voice so you can sing for the rest of your life. At your age, it can be hard to imagine how singing could hurt your voice, but the danger is very real. If you love singing, a voice teacher is probably the best way you can spend your money after food and rent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get questions similar to this quite frequently. There may even be suggestions for answers already.

Bear in mind that most often the best practice to improve something physical is to do that thing. So keep on gently hitting the notes at the ends of your range. At 18 your voice and the physical parts of you that produce sound are nowhere near developed, so settlement is nowhere near, either.

Also bear in mind that the actual sounds sung will help or hinder the extreme ends. Certain vowel sounds in particular will be better at the top end- others won't. So, you need to experiment here to discover.